# Dúvida referente ao IN no Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, where

Estou montando uma query e esbarrei em uma questão.

Minha query está assim:

```
SELECT BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA NIVEL,
       BASI_030.REFERENCIA GRUPO,
       BASI_030.DESCR_REFERENCIA,
       BASI_030.CONTA_ESTOQUE,
       BASI_020.TIPO_PRODUTO
  FROM BASI_030
  JOIN BASI_020
    ON BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = BASI_020.BASI030_NIVEL030
   AND BASI_030.REFERENCIA = BASI_020.BASI030_REFERENC
 WHERE BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2
   AND BASI_030.CONTA_ESTOQUE IN (77, 87, 92)
   AND BASI_030.REFERENCIA IN ( SELECT MCREF.REFERENCIA
                                  FROM MARK_CAMPANHA_REF MCREF
                                 WHERE MCREF.ID_CAMPANHA = 16 )
```

Está funcionando, porém quando a tabela MARK_CAMPANHA_REF não tem nenhuma REFERENCIA, eu teria que trazer todas as referências contidas na tabela BASI_030

Assim como está, quando a tabela MARK_CAMPANHA_REF não tem registros para o ID_CAMPANHA, a consulta não retorna nenhum valor.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria uma mescla de LEFT JOIN com CTE para realizar a lógica.

```
WITH sql AS (
    SELECT BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA NIVEL,
           BASI_030.REFERENCIA GRUPO,
           BASI_030.DESCR_REFERENCIA,
           BASI_030.CONTA_ESTOQUE,
           BASI_020.TIPO_PRODUTO,
           MCREF.REFERENCIA REFERENCIA_MCREF   
    FROM BASI_030   
    JOIN BASI_020
       ON BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = BASI_020.BASI030_NIVEL030    
      AND BASI_030.REFERENCIA = BASI_020.BASI030_REFERENC  
    LEF JOIN MARK_CAMPANHA_REF MCREF
        ON MCREF.ID_CAMPANHA = 16
       AND MCREF.REFERENCIA = BASI_030.REFERENCIA
    WHERE BASI_030.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2    
      AND BASI_030.CONTA_ESTOQUE IN (77, 87, 92) 
)
  , test AS (
    SELECT count(*) qtd
    FROM sql
    WHERE REFERENCIA_MCREF IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM sql
WHERE  (
        CASE
        WHEN ((SELECT qtd
               FROM test) > 0)
          THEN
            REFERENCIA_MCREF IS NOT NULL
        ELSE
          1 = 1
        END)
```

Comment: Oi @Rafael, sim, isso sim. Porém o que eu preciso é... se existir na MARK_CAMPANHA_REF, mostrar somente esses que exitem nas duas, o que o meu código está fazendo. Mas se não existir nenhum registro na tabela MARK_CAMPANHA_REF, mostrar todos os registros da BASI_030. Seria algo como se a subquery que está no IN não retornar nada, mostrar todas as referencias da BASI_030. Não sei se me fiz entender.

Comment: Alterei para incluir possibilidade de usar a lógica. É o LEFT JOIN com CTE.

Comment: Por fim fiz mais alterações e não precisei usar isso, mas funciona legal. Obrigado